# How to test if optional argument has been given?

Tags: functions, optional-arguments

I understand that the last call (`f[1]`) returns `True` because `arg` does not exist and thus `SameQ` tests a single argument (`"ArgValue"`) which always returns `True`. Therefore no comparison can be done here at all. Now it is not possible to use `ValueQ` either, as `arg` does not exist, and thus it has no value so `ValueQ[arg]` would evaluate to `ValueQ[]`. How to test whether `arg` exists or not? I am aware that I can define another signature for just one argument (`f[first_] := ...`), but I want to solve it inside the function, if it is possible.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[first_, arg___] := (arg === "ArgValue");
{f[1, "ArgValue"], f[1, "NonArgValue"], f[1]}
```

> {True, False, True}

**UPDATE**

In general, I want to test whether any optional argument was passed to `f`. Since `f` is in reality a quite large function with a lot of optional arguments and occasionally called with a quite complex argument structure, I decided that I do not want to create complex patterns for each case (i.e. a different signature). Insted I check inside `f` whether any extra argument was passed or not - which in tha baseline case means that there should be **no** extra argument. Thus `f` shouldn't return `False` in reality for only one argument (i.e. it still should perform some computation on its single argument), this is only for testing purposes here. A more realistic function would look like this:

```
ClearAll[func];
func[first_, arg___?overcomplicatedArgumentStructureQ] := Module[{...},
    (* heavy computation *)
    If[argExistQ[arg], (* do this *), (* do that *)];
    (* some more heavy computation *)
];
```

Comment: Based on your update, I think my recommendation of `{} =!= {arg}` is correct.  You are testing the argument on the LHS already, using a test function.   Leonid's `{arg} === {"ArgValue"}` doesn't make sense in this case, and it also assumes a specific value for the optional argument.

Comment: Leonid's answer is correct in the sense that if there is no `arg` given to `f`, it evaluates to `False`, else it also checks whether the given argument equals a certain value. While your solution works as well, I still prefer Leonid's way, as it does the test on the rhs and does not touch the lhs of the function definition (which I implicitly wanted).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I did mention the comparison of `{}` and `{arg}` as a general suggestion as well, in my answer.

Comment: @Leonid In no way did I mean to disparage your answer.  I simply found all of this confusing.  If you find any additional value in my answer feel free to include it in yours.  If you choose to do this I will delete it; otherwise I will leave it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, but in this case I'd keep things as they are, because we clearly interpreted the problem differently. I happenned to pick the interpretation that apparently was what Istvan was after, but IMO your answer is (as always) valuable. I did not vote for it this time though, since I think it solves a slightly different problem, but it does not mean that I find no value in it. Some people may come to this question having exactly the problem which your answer addresses and mine doesn't.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think the two answers can live next to each other perfectly well dealing with slightly different aspects of my question (like lhs/rhs testing), so please don't delete your answer under any circumstances as it provides invaluable solutions for my (and presumably others') unposted questions.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin and Istvan, alright, thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not use something like

```
f[first_, arg___] := {arg} === {"ArgValue"};
```

For general tests, you can compare `{arg}` to `{}`, to determine whether or not the `arg` is empty.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same, +1.  Another possibility is default arguments.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. I thought about default args as well, but did not include them, since that would make things a bit more complex and can possibly create some corner cases which one has to keep in mind.

Comment: @Szabolcs: it won't work with default arguments, just change my code to: `f[first_, arg___ : Automatic] := (arg === "ArgValue")`, which fails the same way at `f[1]`.

Comment: @István It will, but you must use `arg__ : Automatic`, not `arg___ : Automatic`

Comment: @Istvan Well, obviously, you should have used `BlankSequence` with Szabolcs's suggestion: `f[first_, arg__: Automatic] := (arg === "ArgValue")`. This is what I meant by corner cases: you have then to deal with the last arg separately. B.t.w., thanks for the accept.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Leonid: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion for using `BlankSequence`. The whole point of `f` is that it **might** lack all optional arguments, that is why I used `BlankNullSequence`. Could any of you please explain how __ could be used to cover zero argument?

Comment: @Istvan When no argument is at all given, the optional part of the pattern comes into play, and effectively binds `arg` to `Automatic`, so in such case you effectively test `Automatic==="ArgValue"`, which returns `False`.

Comment: Ah, ok, of course that is trivial, silly me. But then why the default value is not triggered, when I use `BlankNullSequence`? I think it was the point where I expected a different behaviour from *Mathematica*. Though I see that `arg` in that case is not bound to anything, but ... why not? I can't see a point why falling back to the default value in case of `BlankNullSequence` would be problematic.

Comment: @Istvan Because the pattern-matcher has to choose which way it goes for patterns like `arg___:default`, and apparently it chooses to bind `arg` to `Sequence[]`. I think, that makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

This question and Leonid's interpretation of it don't make sense to me.

This definition:

```
f[first_, arg___] := (arg === "ArgValue")
```

Will give `True` for `f[1, "ArgValue", "ArgValue"]` while Leonid's method will not.

Perhaps you want:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[first_, arg : "ArgValue" ...] := {} =!= {arg}

{f[1], f[1, "ArgValue", "ArgValue"]}
```

> ```
> {False, True}
> ```

Without seeing your application I can only guess what you are trying to accomplish.  Why are you trying to avoid creating a second definition?  If you want `f[1]` to return `False` isn't

```
f[_] = False
```

the cleanest way?

Comment: Yes, it is a good question why @István used `arg___` and not `arg_`.  If the aim is to allow either one or none at all, an optional argument with a default value is better.  @István, can you clarify?

Comment: @Szabolcs and if you [don't like Default](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6337753/618728) you could use something like: `arg : RepeatedNull["ArgValue", 1]`

Comment: @Szabolcs, Mr.Wizard: I will try to make it more clear tomorrow, no time today.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I have added some clarifications to my question, hope it helps. The problem that Leonid's answer solves is that specific case (all other cases are handled in proper ways) when `arg` does not exist inside `f` but I still want to test its existence (but not its exact value, thus `SameQ` is somewhat unnecessary for the case).